# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo from JPA Console

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpacontainer

I am getting below error whenever I am trying to connect to the Database using **JPA Console**.

I am connecting to oracle 12c DB.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.jpaconsole.engine.impl.query.QueryExcecutorBuilder.build(QueryExcecutorBuilder.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.jpaconsole.engine.query.QueryExecutorManager.getQueryExecutor(QueryExecutorManager.java:59)
    at com.jpaconsole.plugin.Activator.setQueryExecutor(Activator.java:114)
    at com.jpaconsole.plugin.progress.ConfigureJPAOperation.run(ConfigureJPAOperation.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
```

Below screen shot for more visibility
[image]

Here is the screen shot which says in the classpath:
[image]

**Now, I'm getting another error:**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:150)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at com.jpaconsole.engine.impl.query.EntityManagerBuilder.build(EntityManagerBuilder.java:47)
    at com.jpaconsole.engine.impl.query.QueryExcecutorBuilder.build(QueryExcecutorBuilder.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.jpaconsole.engine.query.QueryExecutorManager.getQueryExecutor(QueryExecutorManager.java:59)
    at com.jpaconsole.plugin.Activator.setQueryExecutor(Activator.java:114)
    at com.jpaconsole.plugin.progress.ConfigureJPAOperation.run(ConfigureJPAOperation.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
```

Comment: So put the jar with that class (javax.persistence "persistence-api") in the CLASSPATH. Most basic of all java exceptions ...

Comment: @Billy Frost - Maven project classpath and JPA console both has required jar present.. what is the issue ?